# How can I create the .conf file for a LXC container restored from a backup that comes from Proxmox?

Tags: debian, lxc, proxmox

I can restore the backup with the tar command but I lack the .conf file from the original Proxmox server it comes from.  I restore the backup on a Debian 10 server.

Can I create the .conf file on the fly without copying it from the original Proxmox server ?  If the answer is yes, how can I avoid pitfalls like the following one (occurs after I tried starting the container with a .conf file copied from Proxmox and adapted to the local Debian host) :

```
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.296 ERROR    utils - utils.c:safe_mount:1179 - No such file or directory - Failed to mount "/dev/pts/5" onto "/dev/console"
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.296 ERROR    conf - conf.c:lxc_setup_dev_console:1767 - Failed to mount "/dev/pts/5" on "/dev/console"
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.296 ERROR    conf - conf.c:lxc_setup:3649 - Failed to setup console
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.296 ERROR    start - start.c:do_start:1275 - Failed to setup container "100"
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.297 ERROR    sync - sync.c:__sync_wait:62 - An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 5)
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.297 ERROR    start - start.c:__lxc_start:1951 - Failed to spawn container "100"
lxc-start 100 20210515073414.332 ERROR    lxc_start - tools/lxc_start.c:main:330 - The container failed to start
```

If I try to start the container as privileged, I get the following log :

```
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.778 INFO     lsm - lsm/lsm.c:lsm_init:50 - LSM security driver AppArmor
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.779 DEBUG    terminal - terminal.c:lxc_terminal_peer_default:714 - Using terminal "/dev/tty" as proxy
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.779 DEBUG    terminal - terminal.c:lxc_terminal_signal_init:192 - Created signal fd 9
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.779 DEBUG    terminal - terminal.c:lxc_terminal_winsz:90 - Set window size to 175 columns and 51 rows
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.780 INFO     start - start.c:lxc_init:904 - Container "100" is initialized
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.781 ERROR    start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1693 - Operation not permitted - Failed to clone a new set of namespaces
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.781 DEBUG    network - network.c:lxc_delete_network_unpriv:2362 - Cannot not guarantee safe deletion of network devices. Manual cleanup maybe needed
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.781 DEBUG    network - network.c:lxc_delete_network:3178 - Failed to delete network devices
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.781 ERROR    start - start.c:__lxc_start:1951 - Failed to spawn container "100"
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.782 ERROR    lxc_start - tools/lxc_start.c:main:330 - The container failed to start
lxc-start 100 20210515080033.782 ERROR    lxc_start - tools/lxc_start.c:main:336 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

Comment: I managed to get rid of the error messages and start the container by installing LXC 4.0.6 on Debian 10, hence the same version as the one running on Proxmox 5.

Comment: My question remains unchanged : is there a way to create the .conf file, based on the backup of a container ?